Directional derivative zero - an example. What does it mean (in this example) to move in the direction of the unit vector $u$?
I have hard to wrap my head around this thing,
so a small explanation would be much appreciated.
Here's this example.

I read on this site that if the directional derivative is zero is some direction,
that means the function is constant in that direction.
So I drew this whole example in Geogebra 3D, and I can see that: say I am an ant in the point $T=(2,1,2)$ which lies on the graph of this function, and say I move in the direction of that vector $u = (1/\sqrt{5}, -2/\sqrt{5}, 0)$. But if I do so, then I will just drop off the surface, i.e. I will not stay on the graph of my function $f$, right?
What I notice though is that this vector $u$, when drawn starting at the point $T$ in the 3D space, it seems to be a tangent vector to the level set $f(x,y) = 2$  (which is a circle in 3D space). So maybe that's kind of what it means to move in its direction, I mean if we try to follow $u$ while being at $T$, we will somehow end up going in that circle (the level set $f(x,y)=2$). But that doesn't seem very intuitive, right?
So what exactly does it mean that when we move in the direction of the vector $u$, the function is constant? I don't quite understand it in the context of this example. If I am in the (x,y) plane and I take any direction my function (this inverted bowl) cannot stay constant in any direction, right? So... does it mean I am in the point T and from there I start moving in 3D? Or does it mean I am in the point P and from there I start moving in the $(x,y)$ plane? I am confused on this too, actually that's the first confusion I need to clear.
Here is also my Geogebra drawing here. In that drawing we have $u = \overrightarrow{TT_1} = \overrightarrow{PP_1}$.


It means that the function $\phi(t) = f(x+tu) $ is constant, $u$ being the direction. Some use the notation $df(x;u) = \lim_{t \to 0} {f(x+tu)-f(x) \over t}$. If $f$ is constant on the line $s \mapsto x+su$ then clearly $df(x;u) = 0$, however, it may be that $df(x; u) = 0$ and $f$ is not constant in that direction. For example, if $f(x) = |x|^2$, then $df(0;u) = 0$ for all $u$ but $f$ is not constant.

@copper.hat OK, thanks a lot, yes, these formulas seem familiar, I will think about them too. But I guess I am looking for some geometrical, or even physical intuition here, in this particular example. Because I spent quite some time thinking on this particular example and how it looks like in 3D. So if I am an ant, where should I start moving from, from P or from T and how would that work?! I tend to think I should be moving from P in the (x,y) plane only. Maybe that's the right way to think about it.

Ok, I think I see your confusion. Yes, when the word direction is used, it means the direction in the domain, not the actual direction of movement of the point $(x,f(x))$.

@copper.hat OK, so if I am at P and if I make a really tiny step in the domain $(x,y)$, for example say my step is 0.00001 times the vector u, I will still end up in a point S(x1,y1), and I will get a different value for f(x1,y1), different from f(P)=2, right? So... $f$ is not really constant after I made this tiny step. So I still feel like something is not quite right here :) Doesn't that contradict the info from the link which I am positing below?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492547/what-does-directional-derivative-zeros-imply-when-directional-vector-is-not-zero

I'm not sure what you are asking. If the function is constant along a line, then the directional derivative will be zero. But, as with the scalar function $x \mapsto x^2$ at $x=0$, just because the directional derivative is zero (which it is at $x=0$), clearly does not mean that it is constant. If the directional derivative is zero everywhere on the line then $f$ will be constant on that line.

@copper.hat OK, thanks a lot once again.
